# TIBCO Spotfire - Mashup web player using different domains

Tags: cross-domain, tibco, cross-domain-policy, mashup, spotfire

I'm working on create a web site where I need to embed a [spotfire](http://spotfire.tibco.com/) dashboard.

I've been researching and I found that I can use a [web player](http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Tasks/IntegratingWithWebPlayer.aspx) but they are not hosted under the same domain name, so I'm getting cross site domain errors.

```
SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "https://stage.domain1.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://stage.domain2.com". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "domain1.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
```

Can you please provide me any documentation/experience to fix this situation?

Comment: Not sure which version you are trying to use. You may check the documentation here https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-spotfire-web-player-6-5-2

Comment: Hi @Rao thanks for you quick input. The version is 6.5.2. And I'm using this example as reference: http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Tutorials/WebPlayerOpenFile.aspx

Comment: The problem you mentioned is related to your environment or the link that were present in the example that you mentioned?

Comment: It's related to my environment, I used the example as code base, but I'm using my own domain.

Comment: I wonder if you tried this, but it was not mentioned in the post so far.

[http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Extend/WebApiMultipleServerScenarios.aspx][1]
The link above points to the Tibco documentation but I am not sure if it applies also to the version you work on...

  [1]: http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Extend/WebApiMultipleServerScenarios.aspx

Comment: Hi @JacekSierajewski, I've read that post as well, but that is for work with multiple servers under the same parent domain, but not for multiple parent domains.

Comment: @ArmandoAltamira any solution to this?